# Google Apps Script local Addon development with live reload

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, webpack-dev-server, livereload, esbuild

I am developing a Google Apps Script editor add-on with the following setup:

```
src
|__ client
|__ gas
esbuild.config.js
tsconfig.json
package.json
```

`src/client` is a Svelte app for the add-on UI.
`src/gas` is Google Apps Script code developed.
`esbuild.config.js` has two build processes. The `client` is bundled into one single html file `index.html`. The `gas` code is bundled in one single javascript file `Code.js`.

During development (with [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io) --watch mode), every time I save my code, both `index.html` and `Code.js` are created and pushed automatically to Google server via [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp).

**How can I enable live reload so that every time I save my code, I see the change automatically in my Add-on on Google server?**

[This project](https://github.com/enuchi/React-Google-Apps-Script#-new-local-development-) is able to do that using webpack and React. However I am not sure to understand *conceptually* how. Even after checking the code base.

For now, I am able:

- To push my code to Google server for every save in my editor
- To enable [live reload](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#live-reload) locally with esbuild in-house dev server and a server sent event listener in the final build.
- To create a valid certificate with `mkcert` to enable HTTPS

But I'm not able to trigger a reload of my browser when the files are pushed on Google server.

#### EDIT

Apparently [This project](https://github.com/enuchi/React-Google-Apps-Script#-new-local-development-) is uploading a minimal "dev app" which consists of an iframe pointing to localhost.

Since localhost resolve to Google server, how am I suppose to serve my local files so that the iframe is updated with my local code?

I found [this package](https://github.com/enuchi/Google-Apps-Script-Webpack-Dev-Server) but I don't quite understand the underlying technique used.

Comment: Have you tried setting up your localhost on a different port?

Comment: I did. It doesn't work. Conceptually I don't understand how my script, on Google server, is supposed to resolve 'localhost' to my local dev server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to upload a minimal app on Google Apps Script wrapping an iframe pointing to `https://localhost:5173` (replace the port 5173 with your local dev server port)

Here is my minimal svelte app

```html
<section class="container">
  <iframe
    class="iframe"
    title="app"
    src={`https://localhost:5173`}
  />
</section>
```

Then you need to generate self-signed certificate (you can use `mkcert`)

Then just serve you real app with your local dev server (HTTPS needs to be enabled)

Finally make sure your browser is not blocking the iframe (Brave was blocking it)

It should work!